# list index out of range after sorting through list?

Tags: python, csv

```
def Routine_Maker(number_of_exercises,array):
    routine = []
    i=0
    j=0
    for i in range(number_of_exercises):
        for j in range(2):                
            x = random.randint(0,4)
            movement = array[i][x]
            routine.append(movement)
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
        print (routine)
```

My code searches through a list of exercises stored in the 2 dimensional array called `array` and writes them to an array called `routine`

It searches through the whole file and adds all the workouts, however I get the following message at the end.

```
line 20, in Routine_Maker
    movement = array[i][x]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried doing `for i in range(number_of_exercises-1)` to get it level with the index however this did not work. Any Ideas?

This is what `array` looks like:

```
[['Bench Press', 'Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Cable Flies', 'Cable Crossover'], ['Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Dumbell Press', 'Incline Cable Flies', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Dumbell Flies'], ['Barbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Lateral Raise', 'Face Pulls', 'Dumbell Front Raise'], ['Dumbell Curls ', 'Hammer Curls', 'Preacher Curls', 'Machine Curls', 'Close Grip Chin Ups'], ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions', 'Dips', 'Skullcrushers'], ['Lat Pulldowns', 'Pullups', 'Deadlifts', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Dumbell Rows'], ['Squats', 'Leg Press', 'Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions', 'Leg Curls']]
```

I am trying to randomly select 2 exercises from each array inside the array called `array`. For example, the first array include chest exercises. The next array includes upper chest exercises, then shoulder exercises etc. I want to randomly select 2 from each array/muscle group.

Comment: You are iterating values for i and j, but also incrementing them each time with `i = i + 1`. You are therefore skipping values and eventually try to read outside of the array. You don't need to (and should not) increment these variables manually.

Comment: but it needs to continue throughout the array?

Comment: @DominicCulyer That's what the `for` statement does. It will increment the value of `i` or `j`.

Comment: I have removed it and i still have the same issue

Comment: What are the dimensions of array?  Sample input data would help.

Comment: Print out the values of i, j and x each time to discover when you step outside of the array.

Comment: Read and follow how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your run works fine as long as `number_of_exercises` is not greater than `array.shape[0]` (number of exercises stored in your array).

Comment: However number of exercises needs to be bigger then the length of the array. Is there any way i can switch this round so it will still work

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the lines

```
i=0
j=0
j=j+1
i=i+1
```

When you are using a `for in` loop. You can remove them.

You're likely getting an IndexError because `number_of_exercises` is larger than `len(array)`.

> My guesses based on your edits

```
#!/bin/python

array=[['Bench Press', 'Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Cable Flies', 'Cable Crossover'], ['Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Dumbell Press', 'Incline Cable Flies', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Dumbell Flies'], ['Barbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Lateral Raise', 'Face Pulls', 'Dumbell Front Raise'], ['Dumbell Curls ', 'Hammer Curls', 'Preacher Curls', 'Machine Curls', 'Close Grip Chin Ups'], ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions', 'Dips', 'Skullcrushers'], ['Lat Pulldowns', 'Pullups', 'Deadlifts', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Dumbell Rows'], ['Squats', 'Leg Press', 'Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions', 'Leg Curls']]

import random
def Routine_Maker(array):
    routine = []
    for i in array:
        routine.extend(random.sample(i,2))
    return routine

print(Routine_Maker(array))
# => ['Cable Crossover', 'Bench Press', 'Incline Dumbell Press', 'Incline Dumbell Flies', 'Face Pulls', 'Dumbell Front Raise', 'Preacher Curls', 'Machine Curls', 'Skullcrushers', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions', 'Deadlifts', 'Pullups', 'Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions']
```

What do you want `number_of_exercises` to do when its larger than `len(array)*2`?

Comment: removed and still have the same issue

Comment: "If you're still getting the error it would help if you showed us what data you're putting into the function."

Comment: With your sample data, the code works for me. Just make sure, `number_of_exercises` remains smaller than the number of exercises in your array.

Comment: However number of exercises needs to be bigger then the length of the array. Is there any way i can switch this round so it will still work

Comment: @DominicCulyer absolutely! You just need to provide some more information on what you're trying to achieve. For instance: "I would like to select a specified number of random elements from a 2D array" or "I want to select x number of random elements from each item in an array"

Comment: @DominicCulyer I see your updates but I'm still confused. It's a 2D array (an array of arrays) but do you want it to find a certain number of exercises from each array or just random exercises from any contained array? Can you provide some expected output examples? Thanks

Comment: I would like it to find 2 random exercises for each array. So if you look at the first array (Bench Press, Dumbell Press, Chest Press Machine, Cable Flies, Cable Crossover), i would like it to pull 2 random exercises from here, and then 2 more for the next array and so on.

Comment: @DominicCulyer Ok, I've made some edits and you can see my dilemma at the end. There are more specifics to determine.

Comment: For example, the final output should look like this. ["Chest Press Machine", "Dumbell Press", "Incline Cable Flies", "Incline Chest Press Machine", "Barbell Overhead Press", "Lateral Raise", "Hammer Curls", "Preacher Curls", "Cable Pushdowns", "Dips", "Deadlifts", "Dumbell Rows", "Leg Press", "Squats"[

Comment: As you can see, there are two random exercises from each array inside the 2D array

Comment: @DominicCulyer Ok, see my edits and my question about `number_of_exercises` as well as whether random choices should be unique.

Comment: Basically my program is a workout generator. The user enters the amount of times they can go to the gym, and a workout routine is generated for them. The amount of days they can go to the gym a week is translated into number_of_exercises. So if you can go to the gym 4 days a week,18 exercises need to be generated. Maybe it is easier if we generate 3 from each array? Therefore only one loop is required, and 3 exercises will be pulled (randomly) from each array and therefore 18 exercises in total?

Comment: I was also hoping on in the future changing how many exercises are pulled from each array. For example, 2 exercises from exercises first array (chest exercises), 1 from second array (upper chest array), 3 from third array etc etc. So when he;ping with my solution could you please bear that in mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184780/discussion-between-conner-and-dominic-culyer).

Comment: Is there any chance we could continue this discussion Conner

Answer (score 0):

The for loop already adds 1 to your variables "i" and "j" after every iteration. So, instead of going from 0 to your limit - 1, you are going from 1 to your limit. Just remove the `j = j + 1` and `i = i + 1` lines :)

Edited:

```
def Routine_Maker(number_of_exercises, array):
    routine = []
    for i in range(number_of_exercises):
        x = random.randint(0, len(array) - 1) 
        y = random.randint(0, 4)
        movement = array[x][y]
        routine.append(movement)
    print (routine)
```

Edited #2:

This should do what you told (at least what I understood) :)

```
   def Routine_Maker(number_of_exercises, array):
      routine = []
      pos = 0
      for i in range(number_of_exercises):
            if pos >= len(array):
                pos = 0
            for j in range(2):
                x = random.randint(0,4)
                movement = array[pos][x]
                routine.append(movement)
            pos += 1
      print(routine)
```

This will return an array with `2*number_of_exercises` length. If you want its length to be exactly `number_of_exercises`, the pos index should move every 2 iterations and just delete the `for j` statement :)

Edited #3:

Ok, I think I got it:

First, you have your data:

```
array_of_exercises = [['Bench Press', 'Dumbell Press', 'Chest Press Machine', 'Cable Flies', 'Cable Crossover'], 
                      ['Incline Bench Press', 'Incline Dumbell Press', 'Incline Cable Flies', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Dumbell Flies'], 
                      ['Barbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Lateral Raise', 'Face Pulls', 'Dumbell Front Raise'], 
                      ['Dumbell Curls ', 'Hammer Curls', 'Preacher Curls', 'Machine Curls', 'Close Grip Chin Ups'], 
                      ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions', 'Overhead Barbell Extensions', 'Dips', 'Skullcrushers'],
                      ['Lat Pulldowns', 'Pullups', 'Deadlifts', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Dumbell Rows'], 
                      ['Squats', 'Leg Press', 'Calf Raisers', 'Leg Extensions', 'Leg Curls']]
```

Then, you say how many exercises per day you want:

```
exercises_per_day = [2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

And this would be the function:

```
def Routine_Maker(number_of_days, array, exercises_per_day):
    routine = []
    pos = 0
    for i in range(number_of_days):
      if pos >= len(array):
        pos = 0
      temporal_array = [array[pos][j] for j in random.sample(range(5), exercises_per_day[pos])]
      routine.append(temporal_array)
      pos += 1
    print(routine)
```

So you call it like this:

```
Routine_Maker(10, array_of_exercises, exercises_per_day)
```

And this will get you something like this:

```
[['Cable Flies', 'Cable Crossover'], 
 ['Incline Dumbell Flies', 'Incline Chest Press Machine', 'Incline Dumbell Press', 'Incline Cable Flies'], 
 ['Dumbell Overhead Press', 'Barbell Overhead Press', 'Dumbell Front Raise'], ['Dumbell Curls '], 
 ['Cable Pushdowns', 'Overhead Dumbell Extensions', 'Dips'], 
 ['Dumbell Rows', 'Bent Over Rows', 'Pullups', 'Lat Pulldowns', 'Deadlifts'], 
 ['Leg Press', 'Squats', 'Leg Curls'], 
 ['Dumbell Press', 'Cable Crossover'], 
 ['Incline Cable Flies', 'Incline Dumbell Flies', 'Incline Dumbell Press', 'Incline Chest Press Machine'], 
 ['Dumbell Lateral Raise', 'Face Pulls', 'Dumbell Front Raise']]
```

**It should be noted that:**

- If you say that you want more exercises per day than the ones you have in your array, this will fail because in random.sample you don't get duplicates but the sample size needs to be smaller than the range. If you want more, you'll have duplicates, and you can accomplish this just by modifying it for randomInt.
- When the number of days is bigger than the size of your array of exercises, then it'll start again (that's what `pos` is for).

Comment: Can you show the data you're testing it with? @DominicCulyer

Comment: The `for` loop just overwrites the value of `i` and `j` at the start of each new loop with the next value from the `range`. While superfluous, this cannot be the reason for the error.

Comment: @DominicCulyer I think the edition I made is what you want, if not, let me now :D

Comment: This has fixed the issue. But it does not do what i wanted the code to do. I added some more to the post to further explain what i am trying to do.

Comment: @DominicCulyer check my edit, if I understood wrong, let me know :)

Comment: when running this, the array called routine remains empty? Any ideas why? Print (routine) only outputs []

Comment: @DominicCulyer i just corrected indentation and tried it on an online compiler, works fine

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as intended. Would you like to take this to chat so i can explain more specifically what i am after

Comment: @DominicCulyer sure, where?

Comment: My program is a workout generator. The user enters the amount of times they go to the gym, and a routine is generated for them. The amount of days they can go to the gym a week is translated into number_of_exercises. So if you can go to the gym 4 days a week, 16 exercises need to be generated.I would like a different array created for each day – an array containing the exercises for day 1, an array for the exercises for day 2 etc I need my program to cycle through the array containing the exercises and randomly select a specific amount from each of the arrays within the 2D array

Comment: @DominicCulyer how do you set the number of exercises per day?

Comment: The user selects how many times they wish to go to the gym (either 3x, 4x or 6x per week). 4 exercises are then generated per day.

Comment: So you have an array of arrays. For each day you iterate that array, and get 4 exercises for the corresponding position. And those 4 exercises are random, right? What about duplicates? @DominicCulyer

Comment: I am trying to avoid duplicates. I'm assuming this will only be a simple search through the array to see if the value is already inside the array, and if so, get a new value from the array

Comment: Yes. However i would like to determine how many exercises are generated from each array. So if you look at the array, the first one inside teh 2d array have chest exercises. the next one has upper chest exercises. Then shoulders etc. I would like to be able to change how many are taken from each array. For exmaple, for day 1 we have 2 from the chest array and 2 from the upper chest. for day 2 we have 1 from the bicep, 2 from the shoulder and 1 from the tricep etc.

Comment: Is there any chance the exercises per day can be condensed. Currently in your exa'mple, there are 10 days. Can i change this so maybe the first 3 arrays are combined, then maybe then mayvbe the 4th and 5th etc so that there are only 4 days in total

Comment: Maybve a final if statement at the end that says if days == 4, then add arrays 1, 2 and 3, arrays 4 and 5, etc.

Comment: Hello? you still there?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that `number_of_exercises` is greater than `len(array)`. To fix this you need to validate the input and then do something based on the results of that validation. For example,

```
number_of_exercises = min(number_of_exercises, len(array))
```

What I did here was set `number_of_exercises` to the length of `array` if it's greater than `len(array)`, which would make index errors impossible. Alternatively, you could print some warning/error message informing the user they messed up or do both of these. For example, you could validate it this way:

```
number_of_exercises = int(input("How many? "))
while ((number_of_exercises < 0) or (number_of_exercises > len(array)):
    print ("Invalid input.")
    try:
        number_of_exercises = int(input(Please provide valid input! "))
    catch ValueError:
        number_of_exercises = -1
```

This code disallows the user from moving forward until they've provided valid input. Alternatively, you could show an error message and exit the program:

```
import sys

number_of_exercises = int(input("How many? "))
if (number_of_exercises < 0 or number_of_exercises > len(array)):
    print ("Invalid data provided. This program will now exit")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Trouble with this is number_of_exercises is already defined. In my case, the user selects how many days they wish to attend the gym. The amount of days corresponds to the number of exercises selected which is passed as a value to this function. Therefore i cannot change its value within this function

Comment: In that case, you would validate it before you sent it in. You could check if it's less than the length of the array after the user inputs it and print an error or exit the program if it's greater.

Comment: Could you provide an example